# Quartz scheduling - Run once, then run at specific time (daily)

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I've been playing around with Quartz and I was wondering if it's possible to have a trigger that

Runs when first called, then runs at a particular time (daily) after that

For the running at a particular time I used this:

```
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .StartNow()
                    .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(1, 3))
                    .Build();
```

but I can't see to work out a way of firing once when first called in the same trigger. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 'Runs when first called' what do you mean ?

Comment: @usmanlqbal, sorry, should have explained that better. I mean when the my scheduler class is initialised

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger this job manually using `Scheduler.TriggerJob` method:

> Trigger the identified IJob (Execute it now) - with a non-volatile trigger.

```
scheduler.TriggerJob(new Jobkey("your_job_key"));
```

The identified job can be triggered manually at any time.